# Envio de correo electronico PHPMailer SMTP con estilos CSS

Tags: php, css, gmail, phpmailer

Buenas, estoy tratando de trabajar con la librería `PHPMailer`, que funciona correctamente si no introduzco el método `SMTP`, si añado el método `SMTP` que mi servidor permite configurar, me lanza este mensaje de error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /homepages htdocs/prueba/app/php/class.phpmailer.php:1347 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/htdocs/prueba/app/php/class.phpmailer.php(1426): PHPMailer->getSMTPInstance() #1 /homepages/htdocs/prueba/app/php/class.phpmailer.php(1366): PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #2 /homepages/htdocs/prueba/app/php/class.phpmailer.php(1209): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Mon, 26 D...', '\n\t\t\t\t<head>\t\n\t\t...') #3 /homepages/htdocs/prueba/app/php/class.phpmailer.php(1098): PHPMailer->postSend() #4 /homepages/htdocs/prueba/app/php/configuracion/modif_password_user.php(168): PHPMailer->send() #5 {main} thrown in /homepages/htdocs/prueba/app/php/class.phpmailer.php on line 1347
```

Linea 1347:

```
 public function getSMTPInstance()
    {
        if (!is_object($this->smtp)) {
            $this->smtp = new SMTP; //Linea 1347
        }
        return $this->smtp;
    }
```

También he probado con mi cuenta `GMAIL` y me lanza el mismo fallo.

> Mi código PHP:

```
<?php
//Componemos mensaje de envio

//Obtenemos datos del usuario.
$nombre = ucfirst($_POST['nombre'] ?: '');
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'] ?: '';
$correo = $_POST['mail'] ?: '';

//Incluimos libreria PHPmailer.
require'./../class.phpmailer.php';

//Nuevo correo electronico.
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Caracteres.
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

//Si añado este bloque de codigo me lanza error //////////////////////

//Habilitar la depuración 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               
//Establecer PHPMailer para usar SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();            
//Establecer nombre de host SMTP                      
$mail->Host = "smtp.1and1.es";
//Establecer como verdadero si el host SMTP requiere autenticación 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
//nombre de usuario y contraseña servidor SMTP
$mail->Username = "mi_usuario";                 
$mail->Password = "mi_password";                           
//Si SMTP requiere encriptación TLS
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
//Establecer el puerto TCP para conectarse a
$mail->Port = 587;   

// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#Si elimino dicho bloque funciona correctamente el envio de correo.                  


//De dirección correo electrónico y el nombre
$mail->From = "info@tu_dominio.com";
$mail->FromName = "nombre_dominio";

//Dirección de envio y nombre.
$mail->addAddress($correo, $nombre . " " . $apellidos);
// Responder a
$mail->addReplyTo("info@tu_dominio.com","nombre_dominio");

//BCC -> incluir copia oculta de email enviado.
$mail->addBCC("info@tu_dominio.com");
//Enviar codigo HTML o texto plano.
$mail->isHTML(true);
//Titulo email.
$mail->Subject = "El dominio informa que tu contraseña de acceso fue modificada.";
//Cuerpo email con HTML.
$mail->Body = 
"
<head>  
  <style>       
    body { 
        height: 100%; width: 100%; max-width: 100%;
        font-family: 'Tahoma', arial;  
        background-color: #D8D8D8;
        overflow: hidden;
    }   

    .wit {
        display: block; position:relative;
        width: 100%; max-width:80%;                             
        background-color: #FFF;         
        left:10%;
    }

    .blue { color: #178195; }
    .bold { font-weight: bold; }
    .grey { color: #585858; }
    .padding32 { padding: 32px; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class=wit>
    <div class=padding32>
        <img src='http://mi_dominio.com/img/logotipo-mini.png' style='min-width:100px' />
        <h2 class='inline m-L'><b>Aprende a tu estilo de vida</b></h2>
        <br />

        <span class='bold'> $nombre</span>, tu contraseña fue modificada, en caso que no fuiste tú, ponga se en contacto con info@mi_dominio.com con una breve descripción a tu problema, mantenemos seguro la plataforma.<br />
        <br />
        Se modificó el $fecha_personal, con dirección de IP:  $ip_adres<br />
        <br />

        <h4 class=bold>Atentamente:</h4>
        <span class=grey>Equipo Mi_dominio </span><br />
        Saludos.<br />  
    </div>
    </div>  
</body>
";  

if(!$mail->send()) {
    //error, no se envio el correo  
} else {
    //Se envio correctamente
}

?>
```

> **Nota:** Haciendo pruebas sin utilizar `SMTP` como se puede observar en las imágenes más abajo en algún caso no aplica los estilos `CSS`, en este caso Hotmail (Outlook) abriendo desde escritorio.

¿Alquien sabe porque motivos no se aplican bien los estilos `CSS`, segun tengo entendido deberia aplicar correctamente los estilos en Hotmail (Outlook)?

Hice alguna propia prueba, y en vede utilizar `PHPMailer`, utilice la función `mail()`, y ocurre lo mismo, no aplica siempre bien los estilos `CSS`

Lista de referencia de estilos permitidos:

- http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

**Ejemplos correos recibidos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Configuracion correo SMTP**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta poner el codigo css en bruto y no con clases

Comment: Una vez me pasó un error similar y se solucionó bajando la última versión de phpmailer, prueba con eso.

Comment: Para solucionar el error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SMTP...` debes bajar el archivo [`class.smtp.php`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#minimal-installation)

Comment: @MarcosGallardo, ya probe añadiendo tambien require'./../class.smtp.php'; pero se queda como cargando hasta que al final me lanza un error500 o The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

Comment: @sioesi cuando regreso del trabajo, lo pruebo poner sin clases los estilos pero con id (#), aver si así se aplica correctamente los estilos en cualquier caso.

Comment: @maudichili ayer baje la ultima versión desde github, y sigue el mismo problema. Lo descargo desde: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: ¿Es posible ver el código fuente de alguno de estos correos?

Comment: @SolracRagnarockradio utilizo 1and1 webmail, tambien hice prueba con GMAIL y lanza el mismo fallo. Añado al ejemplo como debe estar la configuración del correo electronico para smtp. Aver si con eso se puede ver algo que este mal configurado en mi código PHP. El codigo fuente es un poco extenso del correo. Otro caso sI no añado el archivo class.smtp.php, me lanza el error de mi ejemplo al principio, y si añado class.smtp.php, se queda como pensando el servidor, hasta lanzarme un error500 o The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

Comment: @sioesi gracias por la observación, ya he solucionado los estilos CSS, aun queda el error SMTP :(, si aplico los estilos directamente a las etiquetas `HTML`, sí que funciona los estilos en los 3 ejemplos probado. Un ejemplo seria: <div style='background-color: #FFF; display: block; position:relative; width: 100%; max-width:80%; margin:0 auto;'>

Comment: ¿Qué te muestra la depuración de PHPMailer?

Comment: @guzgarcia segun tengo entendido hay que poner el SMTPDebug = 2; para diagnosticar los fallos. Si hago una prueba, no manda ningun fallo, simplemente se queda la pagina cargando y esperando segun la url hasta lanzarme el siguiente mensaje: The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later.
744f76d41b4a256061ed6110c4090215 f8119baafff9cd1c18e9d8015e0a914d .......etc

Comment: ¿Has probado a cambiar de proveedor de Hosting?
Tal vez no tenga mucho que ver con tu problema actual, pero te ahorrará, seguro, problemas futuros.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook tiene un detalle, ya que todas las clases de estilo de capa (CSS) las renombra. Ejemplo:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .estilo {
        ...
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="estilo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Al momento de cargar en Outlook este renombrará `<div class="estilo"></div>` por `<div class="x_estilo"></div>` y tal clase no existe en tu CSS, por lo que no se visualiza correctamente.

De recomendación agrega atributos style a cada etiqueta de HTML, no es lo mas optimo pero no tendrás problemas con Outlook.

Comment: Ya lo había solucionado los estilos `CSS`, lo que no me funciona aun es el envió `SMTP`, de todas formas, gracias por la recomendación. +1